# Selective update of mySQL database column

Tags: sql

I would like to update several entries in a mySQL database which I use in combination with Mathematica. But the following code does not work:

Map[
 SQLUpdate[conn, "table_name","column2update", {1}, 
   SQLColumn["selection_column"] = #" ] &,
list_with_selection_values]

The column "column2update" is defined as datatype "Boolean". I would like to insert a "1" (= true) into certain entries. "selection_column" contains unique data (in that case stock symbols). I would like to us the "list_with_selection_values" to identify the entries where I change "column2update" to "1".

Does anyone know why my function does not work? All database connections are ok. Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted has mismatching quotes after `#` to begin with.

Comment: Yes, you are rigth but it is just a typing error here in the forum. My code is ...SQLColumn["selection_column"] = # ] &,... Nevertheless thanks for the tip

Comment: Have you tried using `SQLExecute`? I find it easier to use because you can just do straight sql commands. I have also used it with `Map` as you are trying to do here.

Comment: Yes I tried already SQL Execute: SQLExecute[tradDBconn,
 "UPDATE index_master SET index_master_historical_data =0 WHERE \
FIND_IN_SET(index_master_symbol,('^BTS,^CSO'))"] but I do not know how to create a list in Mathematica the will be look like ('^BTS,^CSO') -> I have about 200 index symbols I would like ti check.

Comment: @Phadreus what's the purpose of the Map? Unless MMA is cleverer than I think it is with SQL its going to be far more efficient to use MMA to generate an IN or a set of OR clauses or even a set of Update statements that you can SQLExecute as one Transaction.  I'm pretty sure doing it the way you currently are will generate round trip IO for each value in the list rather than one round trip during which the updates are executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all of you. I solved the problem. I missed the {} brackets around the database column (I thought I do not need them, if I specify just one column).

Here the final code for later questions:

```
Map[
  SQLUpdate[dbconnection, "database",
    {"column2update"}, {value to be set}, 
    SQLColumn["selection_column"] == # ] &,
 list_with_selection_values]
```